# GDI+, рисование вписанного прямоугольника в bitmap

Tags: c#, gdi+

Имеется код:

```
        Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Black, 8);
        Bitmap bb = new Bitmap(100, 100);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bb);
        g.DrawPolygon(pen1, new PointF[]{
            new PointF(0,0),
            new PointF(100, 0),
            new PointF(100,100),
            new PointF(0, 100),
            new PointF(0, 0)
        });
        bb.Save("test1.bmp");
```

Так вот, в test1.bmp я ожидаю увидеть изображение со вписанном прямоугольником, ширина грани которого будет == pen1.Width
Но ширина грани обычна равна pen1.Width/2. Почему так происходит? И как задавать правильные координаты отрисовки? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Наверное, потому что половина грани находится за пределами области рисования.

Comment: @VadimTagil Почему? Не могу в упор увидеть этого. Отрисовываю по-иному, всё в порядке, но хочется разобраться с этим

Comment: а как вы хотите увидеть нечто за пределами видимого? толщина видимой линии  > 0, соответственно чтобы увидеть всю толщину линии вдоль границы ось линии надо смещать от границы на половину её толщины , как сказал @VadimTagil

Comment: Посмотрите [руководство](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3bssbs7z(v=vs.110).aspx). Возможно, подойдёт задание параметра `Alignment`.

Comment: Вы задали размер Bitmap 100х100, а прямоугольник рисуете 101х101. длина грани считается (x2-x1)+1 = (100 - 0) + 1 = 101. Замените в координатах точек 100 на 99, и получите точно вписанный прямоугольник + комментарий выше от Alexander Petrov

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ваша ссылка очень помогла, большое спасибо, во всём разобрался.